# A system with an Alder Lake CPU fails to reboot under Linux

Tags: fedora, reboot, intel, watchdog

I'm struggling to disable watchdog0 on my newly installed fedora.

I can restart the system after installation, but once I run `dnf upgrade --refresh` I can no longer reboot. I get a message saying

`watchdog: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop`

I've tried various ways of disabling it. including -

`sudo sysctl kernel.nmi_watchdog=0`

(this returns `kernel.nmi_watchdog = 0` and running `cat /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog` seems to verify that it's disabled)

I've tried disabling it in sysctl.conf with

`sudo sh -c "echo 'kernel.nmi_watchdog=0' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"`

and then running `sudo sysctl -p` to disable it immediately.

I can't seem to find anyway of rebooting my system.

It's running on an alder lake cpu (just in case that could be causing issues - I saw a message mentioning intel once - I've included an image below).

[image]

What should I do? How do I get this running properly?

Answer (score 3):

I believe watchdog has nothing to do with this issue but something about the Linux kernel doesn't work correctly with ADL CPUs: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215271

Please try to use other reboot methods and report in the bug report which one works for you: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BIOSandUbuntu#Reboot_Methods

*"watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!"* is a very common message for desktop motherboards most of which actually don't have a real watchdog device.

It's worth noting that it *is* safe to reboot/power off your PC using physical buttons on your case because the Linux kernel flushes all the data to your storage prior to rebooting/powering off.